How can I get my search box not to displace adjacent components in the header?
This is the Bootstrap header of my page which contains a logo on the left, a search box in the middle and menu items on the right:
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body py-3 mb-4" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #eaebee">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="#">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/Screenshot%20from%202024-07-08%2010-49-59.png">
      </a>
      <button data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-target="#navcol-2">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Toggle
          navigation</span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-2" style="justify-content: flex-end;">
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-center" style="flex-grow: 3;">
          <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
            <app-product-search></app-product-search>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active  d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#userSignInModal">
              <div class="d-xl-flex justify-content-center">
                <i class="fa fa-user d-inline-block" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
              </div>
              <small *ngIf="!user" class="d-inline-block">Sign In</small>
              <small *ngIf="user" class="d-inline-block">{{user.lastName}}</small>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center" [routerLink]="['/cart']">
              <div class="d-xl-flex justify-content-center">
                <i class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down d-inline-block" style="font-size: 18px;"></i>
              </div>
              <div>
                <small class="d-inline-block">Cart</small>
                <small class="ms-1">({{numberOfItems}})</small>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

The search box is an embedded child component: .
This is the html of the child component:
<div id="div5" *ngIf="searchResults?.length">
  <ol class="list-group d-block">
    <li key="{item}" class="py-1 px-2 list-group-item" *ngFor="let product of searchResults">
      <a (click)="resetSearchResults()" [routerLink]="['/selectedProduct', product._id]">{{product.description}}</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

The problem is whenever search results are produced in the child component, the length of the entire header is increased so as to display the results. The logo on the right of the search box and the menu items on the right end up in the middle of the page. I thought making the css position of the search results static would then display it without affecting the adjacent items but that's not working. I have done something similar before but cannot find the code I used.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I gave the top-level div of the child component a position of relative and the ol element within a position of absolute. Problem solved.
<div style="position: relative;"
  id="search-column">
   <ol
    class="list-group d-block"
    style=" position: absolute; top: 10; left: 0; z-index: 10;"
    *ngIf="showSearchResult"
  >
    <li key="{item}" class="py-1 px-2 list-group-item list-group-item-warning" 
      style="border: 1px solid"
      *ngFor="let product of searchResults">
      <a [routerLink]="['/selectedProduct', product._id]"
         (click)="setSelectedProduct(product._id)">{{
        product.description
      }}</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

